# Scientists/explorers discover a spaceship in jungle with human occupants

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

I (think) I remember reading a short story or novella about 40 years ago that told the story of scientists/explorers who discover a spaceship in the jungle.

Once they are able to access the interior of the ship they find humans instead of aliens, the implication being we are all descended from alien beings/outer space.

**Does anyone remember a story like this or did I dream it?**

Comment: http://www.personapaper.com/article/20650-short-science-fiction-story-review--brian-w-aldiss--our-kind-of-knowledge - Not jungle.

Answer (score 2):

In Kay Kenyon's [*The Seeds of Time*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004G606HQ)  a human(ish) spaceship is found overgrown by/grown into an alien jungle

Book I Green Shifting, ch. *Beyond Eden:*

> She rose and turned to a ledge on the opposite bulkhead. Here, the odd
>   colors of tan and white lay untouched by biotic growth. Barely visible
>   tracery showed what Clio immediately recognized as star charts. She
>   bent close to examine the lines and runes, but the dim light revealed
>   little except, here and there, what might be a number. A recognizable
>   number. Her eyes must be making things up. Too dim to be sure. She
>   lifted the page and found others beneath it, but the top one crumbled,
>   littering the next sheet with debris.
>  She turned to the
>   instrumentation again, poking at the console, peeling a layer of moss
>   from a small section. Her hand shook slightly as the thought took
>   root. *There are explorers in the universe. Like us. At least a little
>   like us.* Using her small utility knife, she dug into the panel
>   itself, which gave way like the soft threads of banana skins. Beneath,
>   green fuzzy wires looped methodically through a series of small,
>   corrugated sections. As she scraped at them, clear, faceted
>   protrusions sparkled. Though everything supported its growth of plant
>   life, each ship component was strangely intact, each wire separately
>   coated in Niang turquoise.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds very similar to Sphere by Michael Chrichton. There are differences though. In Sphere the space craft is at the bottom of the ocean and it is from the future.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how/why this fits the OP's criteria?